# jQuery remove don't work when run over maped set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code like this:

```
  $('#mb-history').on('click', '#post-edit .buttons .delete', function() {
    var files = $('.files input:checked').map(function() {
      return $(this).closest('.file');
    });
    var ids = files.map(function() {
      return $(this).data('id');
    }).get();
    console.log(ids);

    files.remove(); // this don't work

    return false;
  });
```

and files.remove() don't work the element stay in the DOM. (console.log show array with element I've selected). My html look like this:

```
<div class="files ui-helper-clearfix" style="display: block;">
    ...
    <div class="file" data-id="13835">
      <img src="/thumb.php?src=moja-budowa%2F611%2FMB_Z3_611_13835.jpg&amp;size=90&amp;height=64&amp;nologo" alt="">
      <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

What's wrong with my code? I'm using jquery-1.8.2.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EQ8yk/)**

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a [JSFiddle](http://JSFiddle.net) showing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found, instead of map I can just put closest after set:

```
var files = $('.files input:checked').closest('.file')
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have `files` references for removing or any other action.. $.map() create a new array. Change:

```
var files = $('.files input:checked').map(function() {
  return $(this).closest('.file');
});
```

to

```
var files = $('.files input:checked').parent();
```

Comment: While this also works, it is less robust than the asker's earlier solution of using `closest('.file')` (if the hierarchy may change).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Yep, but more faster

Comment: "faster" is only an issue if it is "slow" in the first place. This example is happening at user input rates, so speed is not as important as ease of maintenance *in this case*. You would not notice any difference at all unless he marked 1000's of entries for deletion at once :)

Answer (score -1):

```
files
[
    e.fn.e.init[1]
    0: div.file
    context: input
    length: 1
    prevObject: e.fn.e.init[1]
    selector: ".closest(.file)"
    __proto__: Object[0]
]


files[0].remove()
```